# OpenID and URL Rewriting

Tags: url, openid, url-rewriting

I am having a problem implementing OpenID on my ASP.NET site. I have got OpenID to work well when the return URL ends in .aspx, however whenever i try and return it to a rewriten URL (http://example.com/return/ is really http://example.com/return.aspx) it doesn't work.

How can i set the rewrite rule so that OpenID will work.

I am using the Intelligencia.UrlRewriter DLL

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more about what "doesn't work"?  Hard to tell you how to fix it without details on what's broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since moved to the MVC framework which doesn't add the .aspx extension anyway.

Thanks for the help anyway Chacha102.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make return.aspx the default.aspx in the /return/ directory?

(I don't know much about that specific DLL, just standard knowledge about directories.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i have decided to just have it return to the ASPX page. I can deal with rewriting later.